# Pointer to a Component

Tags: delphi, pointers, reference, components

I have a single PopupMenu item where the TMenuItem tag changes according to which button calls it. Each button has its own TEdit (ResultTFile1, ResultTFile2 and ResultTFile3). These TEdits are created with the Form Designer.

```
var
 TempResultFile : TEdit;
begin
 // Find the right TEdit
 case (Sender as TMenuItem).Tag of
  1: TempResultFile := ResultTFile1;
  2: TempResultFile := ResultTFile2;
  3: TempResultFile := ResultTFile3;
 end;

 // Call save function
 if (SaveDialog1.Execute) then TempResultFile.Text := SaveDialog1.FileName;
end;
```

However, it doesn't work. The Dialog opens, but after execution, the FileName variable is not given to the real TEdit.Text (ResultTFile1, ResultTFile2 and ResultTFile3). There's no error. There's just nothing. The debugger doesn't seem to react -- but then, I could be wrong. If I understand this well, it's because the value is given to TempResultFile and not the real TEdit. How can I code it in a way where TempResultFile **points** to the component?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Show where `ResultTFile1` etc. are declared. And tell us what "it doesn't work means". That's never enough info. Complete error message and point in code where error is raised are required.

Comment: OK, there's no error, there's just nothing. Does the file dialog show? What happens when you run the code under the debugger? What path is taken?

Comment: `TempResultFile` does point to the component. An object reference is just that, a reference. Split the if/then statement onto two lines so that you can check whether or not `SaveDialog1.Execute` is returning `True` or `False`. Do that under the debugger.

Comment: Maybe you'd use just use readymade TEdit with integrated OpenFile button inside ?

Comment: Enable Use Debug DCUs option and use debugger in View / Debug Windows / CPU Window, tracing sub-pascal commands. You would probably be able to trace into text-setting methods and Debug Windows / Evaluate values like Self.Name to see where are you going.
///
*case 1:  ...; 2:...; 3:...; else raise Exception.Create ('Wrong button tag!!!'); end;*
/// at function end put ShowMessage(Format('%x, %x, %x, %x', [integer(pointer(TempResultFile)), integer(pointer(ResultFile!)),  ... File3))])); Check if addresses match is they should

Comment: Some _debugging_ logic: When the dialog appears (thus the routine runs) and no edit is filled, then, given the above code, the only conclusion that can be made is that `SaveDialog1.FileName` is empty or that `SaveDialog1.Execute` returns `False`. Otherwise `TempResultFile` shouldn't point to any edit which would result in an access violation.

Comment: @Arioch'The: There's no reason to enable debug DCUs here. Simply stepping through the code as-is in the debugger would show the problem; stepping into the VCL/RTL is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Well, that would allow to check Self.Name inside SetText handler. Soemtimes it is rather easy way to check for zero or wrong pointers. Or for error s in libraries or compiler.

Comment: @Arioch'The, you don't need to do it in `SetText`. You can check for nil or wrong pointers right there, and in the code that's shown there are no bad libraries used, and we know Delphi' compiler isn't wrong. You can tell all that right  here without the debug dcu's being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, there are only so many things that can go wrong with the code you have shown:

1) the `TMenuItem.Tag` may contain the wrong value.

2) `TempResultFile` may not be assigned a valid `TEdit` pointer.  Despite what others have said, leaving the variable uninitialized DOES NOT guarantee that an Access Violation will occur, though it is likely. There is also the possibility that if the `TEdit` was not created correctly, or has been freed, that the pointer being assigned may be nil.  That will cause an AV if you try to use it.

3) `SaveDialog1.Execute()` may be returning False.  That happens if you cancel the dialog, but it can also happen if the dialog has an internal error.  In some situations, you can use `CommDlgExtendedError()` to check for that condition.

4) `SaveDialog1.FileName` is empty, which should not happen if `SaveDialog1.Execute()` returns true, however it can happen if you are using a fairly modern Delphi version, running your app on Windows Vista or later, and select a non-filesystem file.

During your debugging, make sure you are checking for all those conditions, eg:

```
var         
  Item: TMenuItem;
  TempResultFile : TEdit;         
  S: String;
begin         
  Item := Sender as TMenuItem;

  case Item.Tag of         
    1: TempResultFile := ResultTFile1;         
    2: TempResultFile := ResultTFile2;         
    3: TempResultFile := ResultTFile3;         
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('%s.Tag (%d) is not an expected value!', [Item.Name, Item.Tag]);
  end;         

  if TempResultFile = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('TempResultFile is nil!');

  if not SaveDialog1.Execute then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('SaveDialog1.Execute returned false! Possible CommDlg error? (%d)', [CommDlgExtendedError()]);

  S := SaveDialog1.FileName;
  if S = '' then
    raise Exception.Create('SaveDialog1.FileName is empty!');

  TempResultFile.Text := S;
end;
```

As an alternative to using the `TMenuItem.Tag`, the `TPopupMenu.PopupComponent` property will tell you which Button displayed the PopupMenu.  You can set the `TButton.Tag` property to point at the `TEdit` component that corresponds to that Button, then you don't have to use the `TMenuItem.Tag` property anymore to hunt for the `TEdit` component, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ResultTButton1.Tag := NativeInt(ResultTFile1);
  ResultTButton2.Tag := NativeInt(ResultTFile2);
  ResultTButton3.Tag := NativeInt(ResultTFile3);
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  ResultTButton : TButton; 
  TempResultFile : TEdit; 
begin 
  ResultTButton := PopupMenu.PopupComponent as TButton; 
  TempResultFile := TEdit(ResultTButton.Tag); 
  if TempResultFile <> nil then begin
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
      TempResultFile.Text := SaveDialog1.FileName; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: -1 This also doesn't explain what the problem is with the code in the Q

Comment: Clearly you don't like VanillaH's question, but please stop downvoting everyone's answers for it! You are pissing everyone off now. This is not acceptable behavior for this site.

Comment: My code may not provide a solution to the original problem, but it is a viable alternative that does not require the event handler to be hard-coded for the possible TEdit controls it can look at.

Comment: "My code may not provide a solution to the original problem" That is my point. I agree that your use of PopupComponent is nicer than the approach in the Q. But answers are meant to answer the question. This does not, as you yourself have stated. Sorry, but if that's not worth a downvote, what is? Rather than being pissed off, you should remedy your answer.

Comment: @David, maybe since everyone is disagreeing with you, *you* should step back and look at the ridiculous stance you're taking here. We get it-the text of the question doesn't meet your approval. That doesn't make attempts to help the asker automatically wrong. You're not only providing a negative impression to a new user here, you're being snarky to everyone actually trying to help with a solution. Perhaps you should review your attitude instead. (I disagree with Remy's answer because the poster is obviously new to Delphi and I think this solution is a little advanced, but no downvote.)

Comment: @Ken I see upvotes on my comments. I think not everyone disagrees with me. Clearly you and Remy do. What's wrong with disagreement, argument and debate? Isn't that a good thing. My downvotes to the answers are not because I don't like the question. They are because these answers fail to answer the question that was asked. SO is a Q and A site. Good SO users are meant to vote. Up for good answers, down for bad answers. Ad hominem attacks don't help.

Comment: And I see upvotes on mine to you. There's no attack here-you said "pissed off". Downvotes are not meant for you not liking the question being answered-they're for voting down wrong/bad answers. Neither mine or Remy's is wrong-the fact you don't like the question asked is your excuse for DVs, and that's as wrong as people who revenge DV because they don't like being DV'd. My answer provides a solution that will either fix the problem or identify where it's being caused (see the list I added). Remy's won't identify the problem, but might fix it, and isn't "wrong". Either educates the poster.

Comment: @David, in addition to the above, also note that the upvotes you're getting on your comments are not on those made to my answer or Remy's.

Comment: @ken Read carefully. Remy said "pissed off", not me. There are plenty of ad hominem attacks here. Your comments describing supposed answers of mine in the past. That is classic ad hominem. I don't understand the need for that. I downvoted the answers for their sake, I already explained that.

Comment: Perhaps the actual code has a top level exception handler that swallows all exceptions!!

Comment: (1) A wrong tag in the code in the question would lead to an uninitialized edit, which in fact is your second point. (2) The code in the question clearly shows it is not a freed edit, hence I see no practical value of your assessment that setting the text property DOES NOT guarantee an AV.

Comment: My second point included another possibility for a bad `TEdit` pointer besides just a bad `Tag` value. There is nothing in the original code to indicate that it is not a freed `TEdit`. It is assigning a variable to a variable, so whose to say the original variable is even valid to begin with? Granted, it LIKELY is valid, but the code should not assume that, especially when trying to troubleshoot the problem. Setting the `Text` using an invalid `TEdit` variable DOES NOT guarantee an AV. An unitialized variable contains a random value, so it depends on what memory block ends up being accessed...

Comment: ... An AV means an invalid memory address was accessed.  Accesing an incorrect but valid memory address from an uninitialized pointer will not raise an AV, though the result may be garbage.

Comment: An Edit that was created with the designer (as in the question) will vanish when it is freed. I find it very very unlikely to go unnoticed (in fact we know it since OP tells the edits' text are not set, so he sees the edits), there is no point in talking about freed/incorrectly created edits in this question. And I know what an AV is. Setting the Text property on an uninitialized variable will not access only one random memory address. It will jump from hoop to hoop for a good time. Not getting an AV on such an occasion, while theoretically possible, practically is quite impossible.

Comment: @Remy True, but we can only clutch at straws. Perhaps the user switched off break on errors in the debugger.

Comment: @Remy, what would happen if DFM would have some Tag set for some ResultTButton ? Won't be more reliable to set tags in OnShow event instead ?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz that can happen if what he sees is for example TEdit4 not TEdit1. There can be GUI box with another var attached or even without var at all. Also some stray TEdit1 := ... line could chaneg the value of var but not free original component.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug your code and work out what the problem is, change your code entirely – the comments explain how each works to help you solve the problem.

```
var
  TempResultFile : TEdit;
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then    // Only try assignment if file chosen
  begin
    // Find the right TEdit
    // The default branch will be used if the wrong menu item is 
    // connected to the event, or you forgot to set the tag value
    case (Sender as TMenuItem).Tag of
      1: TempResultFile := ResultTFile1;
      2: TempResultFile := ResultTFile2;
      3: TempResultFile := ResultTFile3;
    else                     // If none of the above match
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid tag %d in %s', 
         [TMenuItem(Sender).Tag, TMenuItem(Sender).Name]));
    end;
    // At this point, we know TempResultFile has been assigned a value
    TempFileResult.Text := SaveDialog1.FileName;
  end
  else // User clicked cancel on SaveDialog1.
    ShowMessage('SaveDialog1.Execute returned False`);
end;
```

This does several things that will help you:

- If the `SaveDialog` doesn't appear, you know you didn't assign the OnClick handler for a menu item.
- If the user chooses `Cancel` on the `SaveDialog`, it returns false, and this will show you a dialog to indicate that fact (to eliminate that problem).
- If the user chooses a file, it checks to make sure that a valid `Tag` assignment was made for the `TMenuItem`, and raises an exception if you forgot (and gives you the invalid tag value and the name of the component that was clicked).

In addition, it's safer code than what's in your original question, which can cause an access violation if the tag is not one of the values in your `case` statement and the `SaveDialog1.Execute` returns true. (There may be nothing assigned to `TempResultFile` when you access it's `Text` property.)

Once you've figured out what you're doing wrong, you can remove the final

```
end
else 
  ShowMessage('SaveDialog1.Execute returned False`);
```

Comment: @David, this is *entirely* different code, and will identify the problem the poster is having with his own code. It's better than posting comments about a poor quality question and downvoting valid attempts to provide a solution. You've posted answers to literally dozens of questions of lower quality than this one, and collected tens of thousands of rep points doing so.

Comment: No, the code is to all intents and purposes just the same as in the Q. If the TEdit local was not being assigned to then there'd be an AV. If Execute was returning False then the user has clicked Cancel on the dialog. The question makes no sense. It's not a real question. Adding lots of spurious answers doesn't help.

Comment: @David: First, this code isn't the same. It only tries to read the tag and make the assignment if `SaveDialog.Execute` returns true, and notifies the user if it returns false; that helps identify the problem as an issue with the last line (orig. code) not being executed. If the return is true, it handles the case of a different menu item or forgetting a `Tag` assignment (the  exception). Third, it prevents any AV by making sure that the assignment to `TempFileResult` actually was made (with the default in the case statement). It's totally different. That's OK. Knock yourself out.

Comment: Clearly the local variable is assigned since there's no AV. According to the comments, there's no AV to prevent. We can't imagine that the user is clicking Cancel. Therefore the code in the Q does not match the reported symptoms. The right course of action is close as not real question.

Comment: Clearly it may not be, because the call to SaveDialog1.Execute might return false. Again, David, it's fine. Enjoy. If you'd like, I can post links to other less than great questions that people have posted answers to that got upvoted (and even accepted), and you can go downvote them as well. I can even find some of your own, and you can go back and delete your answer and downvote all the others, and some that have no answers yet you can lurk on watching for help efforts. I prefer to be helpful when possible. If you don't, that's fine. You've got lots of rep to throw away snarkily downvoting.

Comment: Returns false when user cancels dialog

Comment: Which means in the original code, if SaveDialog returns false the assignment could have not been made and the user wouldn't know, which is **exactly** what I've pointed out twice to you now. Whatever. There are obviously issues with the question - David didn't approve it's content, and therefore all attempts to help must be punished until the poster complies. You don't like the question, downvote **it** instead of punishing people trying to be helpful.

Comment: Almost impossible to imagine user is clicking cancel. If that is so then the answer should be "click save and don't click cancel". That's the only answer that explains this mystery.

Comment: @David. Whatever. Like I said, knock yourself out. I'm tired of repeating myself when you're obviously not reading what I write. Maybe the poster will stop by, edit the post, you can bless it, and it will quit costing you "oodles of rep". (Or you could just stop wasting the rep downvoting technically correct answers needlessly - your choice, obviously.)

Comment: @Remy: Thanks for the syntax fix. Been reading a lot of `c` code lately. :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can write it like this:

```
begin
  if (SaveDialog1.Execute) then 
  begin
    case (Sender as TMenuItem).Tag of    
       1: ResultTFile1.text := SaveDialog1.FileName;    
       2: ResultTFile2.text := SaveDialog1.FileName;    
       3: ResultTFile3.text := SaveDialog1.FileName;   
    end;  
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: -1 This is equivalent to the code in the question. This question cannot be answered at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

Well...there's really only one reason why your code doesn't work: TempResultFile is not being assigned, meaning the "case" statement is failing to find a match. Either:

- Sender is *not* an instance of TMenuItem
- Sender is not the instance of TMenuItem you're expecting
- Sender is your TMenuItem
  but you're not properly assigning the tag

Each case is super-easy to verify. Get to work!

Oh, as an aside, proper defensive style would re-write that code as:

```
var
 TempResultFile : TEdit;
begin
 {$IFDEF DEBUG}
 // preconditions
 Assert(sender is TMenuItem) ;
 {$ENDIF}
 // Find the right TEdit
 case (Sender as TMenuItem).Tag of
     1: TempResultFile := ResultTFile1;
     2: TempResultFile := ResultTFile2;
     3: TempResultFile := ResultTFile3;
     else Assert(false,'Failed to locate the proper TEdit') ;
 end;

 // Call save function
 if (SaveDialog1.Execute) then 
     TempResultFile.Text := SaveDialog1.FileName;
```

end;

Comment: (1) `(Sender as TMenuItem)` would raise an AV, (2) The dialog wouldn't open, (3), Accessing `Text` of non-instantiated TempResultFile would raise an AV.

Comment: -1 for the reasons sertac lists. This Q is costing me oodles of rep!

Comment: Sertac/David: OK, fine, whatever. HTH do you know an AV isn't being raised when a NIL TempResultFile is assigned? Psychic debugging powers? Because the original question didn't indicate whether an external global exception handler is in place, whether the IDE is set to break on all exceptions or just unhandled exceptions, etc.

I'm with Ken -- it's ridiculous to downvote attempts to help with this badly-put request. And David: you're right, this Q is costing you oodles of rep, 'cause I've definitely lost respect for you over how you've handled this particular question.

Comment: It's a shame you reacted that way. I didn't  rate your answer and downvoted. That's how it's meant to work. If question's are badly-put then the best response is to ask for clarification. It it doesn't come then vote to close. Again, that's how SO is designed to work.

Comment: > *".. an AV isn't being raised when a NIL TempResultFile ..*" > And how is that relevant?

Comment: You listed as reasons why my code was unnecessary "Accessing Text of non-instantiated TempResultFile would raise an AV"; i.e., you were saying essentially "since no AV is being raised, your code is unnecessary". I was merely pointing out that there's no evidence given that such an AV wasn't being raised.

Comment: @Erik - I said nothing about your code. In fact I didn't even read it. What I said was that the three reasons you listed could not possibly have been the cause of the problem in the question.